# updates in mongodb not getting pushed in elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mongo-river

I am using elasticsearch and mongodb. Setup river week ago. Today on searching records just check the elasticsearch index are not getting updated or modified as records in mongodb are added daily.

I am using following lines to create river

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_river/myindex/_meta" -d '
{
"type": "mongodb",
"mongodb": {
"host": "localhost",
"port": "27017",
"db": "qna",
"collection": "collection"
},
"index": {
"name": "myindex",
"type": "index_type"
}
}'
```

Comment: I think you need to re-index your elastic search cluster after every insert to the mongo database, or it will not update?